# How to get Apigility working correctly?

Tags: php, laminas-api-tools

I am working on installing Apigility on a Linux web server. It is a shared hosting account with Inmotion Hosting. I am using the instructions at https://apigility.org/documentation/intro/installation. It was really easy to install, but I running into syntax error that I can't figure out.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in /home/amlcon5/public_html/websites/dev/apigility/vendor/zendframework/zend-servicemanager/src/ServiceManager.php on line 281
```

Here is the function from ServiceManager.php where the error is.

```
/**
 * Set factory
 *
 * @param  string                           $name
 * @param  string|FactoryInterface|callable $factory
 * @param  bool                             $shared
 * @return ServiceManager
 * @throws Exception\InvalidArgumentException
 * @throws Exception\InvalidServiceNameException
 */
public function setFactory($name, $factory, $shared = null)
{
    $cName = $this->canonicalizeName($name);

    if (!($factory instanceof FactoryInterface || is_string($factory) || is_callable($factory))) {
        throw new Exception\InvalidArgumentException(sprintf(
            'Provided factory must be the class name of a factory, callable or an instance of "%s".',
            FactoryInterface::class // <--- ERROR IS HERE
        ));
    }

    if ($this->has([$cName, $name], false)) {
        if ($this->allowOverride === false) {
            throw new Exception\InvalidServiceNameException(sprintf(
                'A service by the name or alias "%s" already exists and cannot be overridden, please use an alternate name',
                $name
            ));
        }
        $this->unregisterService($cName);
    }

    if ($shared === null) {
        $shared = $this->shareByDefault;
    }

    $this->factories[$cName] = $factory;
    $this->shared[$cName]    = (bool) $shared;

    return $this;
}
```

I have tried several things, such as: reinstalling using other methods, disabling OpCache, and reviewing the config files.

Has anyone experienced this when setting up Apigility or know how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I wasn't up to date on PHP. Updated to PHP5.5 and it worked.